# Twig For loop array

Tags: php, for-loop, twig

i have a array like this and want to get the content.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => Testnews
            [title] => Testnews
            [2] => Dies ist eine kleine <strong>Testnews!</strong>
            [text] => Dies ist eine kleine <strong>Testnews!</strong>
            [3] => 1
            [type] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [timestamp] => 1
            [5] => 0
            [status] => 0
        )

)
```

I tried the following:

```
                    {% for latest_news in news %}
                        {% for id, title in latest_news %}
                            id : {{ id }}
                            title : {{ title }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

That works, but i don't think this is the right way to do this.

How should it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the right and easiest solution:

```
                {% for latest_news in news %}
                     id : {{ latest_news.id }}                      
                     title : {{ latest_news.title }}                      
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Mis-read your array (ignore my answer).  Yeah, that's definiately the way forward.

Comment: I forgot that you can access a array directly if you add the dot. But thanks anyways. Maybe this hels anyone ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that's right.  You could also do:

```
{% for latest_news in news %}
    {% for news_item in latest_news %}
         id: {{ news_item.id }}
         title: {{ news_item.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```